# Pushing master to different remote branch netbeans GIT integration

Tags: git, branch, push, netbeans-8, git-remote

I want to do something that looked very simple at the beginning but seems not to be so straightforward using netbeans git integration:

I have a local master branch I want to push to a remote branch but, here's the catch, with a different name say "origin/mymaster".

I know how to do it with command-line git but can't figure out how to do it with the netbeans integration. I have no prob in using command line but other collaborators of the project do and would love to stick to netbeans alone and stil be able to do this.

Can you do this in anyway using the netbeans git wizards?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't find the option Push branch in the GIT Integration with Netbeans

Comment: Which GIT plugin are you using in Netbeans?

Comment: It's not a plugin, it's the standard git-netbeans integration that comes with the standard netbeans 8.0.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a workaround as also suggested by VonC. I created a local branch named mymaster (which is the branch name I want to push to on the remote) and then pushed that one using the netbeans wizard.

It works but I would have prefered to have the option of pushing master:origin/mymaster directly in netbeans since it's something you can do natively in git command line.

Enea

Comment: I agree, choosing directly the name of the remote branch would be more practical. But isn't this workaround what I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Yes, that's why I credited you in the answer above :) and upvoted your comment

Answer (score 1):

The [NetBeans push wizard](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#push) include a step 4 where:

[image: https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/74/ide/git/push.png]

> At the `Update Local References` page, choose the branch(es) to be updated in the Remotes directory of your local repository and click Finish.
>   The specified remote repository branch is updated with the latest state of your local branch.

So <del>you should be able to select a different branch at that stage</del>.
Since the [OP neneitaly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3351920/neneitaly) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304805/pushing-master-to-different-remote-branch-netbeans-git-integration/33314464?noredirect=1#comment54531898_33314464) it is not possible, that leaves only the workaround of creating a local branch (where `master` is) with the right target name, and pushing that branch.

Comment: Nope this does not solve the issue. The branches you want to push to are selected at stage 2. "select local branches" and there you're forces to choose a remote branch whose name matches the local one. I.e. I cannot push local/master -> remote/branch1.

BTW Step 3. Update Local references only creates the remote tracking ref of the type origin/branchname on the local repository (see http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches/ for a description of a remote tracking branch)

Comment: @neneItaly then you would need to create a local branch (branch1) where master is, and push that local branch which would then have the right target name.